# Changes in Laravel Blade view not reflected in webpage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having a strange problem when updating a Blade view in a Laravel project hosted on a Linux CentOS server. The changes I make (deleting or commenting out a line of html) are not reflected on the webpage. I tried clearing the view cache with `php artisan view:clear` to no avail. When I go to `/var/www/app/storage/framework/views` and check the compiled php view the changes are there, but they still don't show up on the webpage. The old version of the view must still be stored somewhere, I just can't figure out where. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: As an addendum, I also tried `php artisan cache:clear` as well as clearing the browser cache and neither worked.

Linux CentOS release 7.3.1611;

Apache 2.4.6;

PHP 7.1.7;

MySQL 5.5.52-MariaDB;

Laravel 5.3.31.

Comment: config:cache, cache:clear, optional try ctr+shift+r in browser

Comment: Have you tried just clearing the cache of your browser?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all of the above, no results.

Comment: Have you checked if you are using opcache? Also check for any additional cache that might come from nginx or apache configurations

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
php artian view:clear
```

OR for broad prospective, run

```
php artian optimize:clear // This is available for post Laravel 6 versions
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome open dev tools, then settings and check disable cache
option

[image: How to disable chrome caching]

It works like a charm for me.